# Script with a recursive prompt for file management?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

My apologies, I'm new to BASH scripting and may be in the wrong place. I've just bought a new Mac and am trying to write BASH scripts. My first attempt will help me move files from my Downloads directory.

I'd like to have a programme that asks me for a search string to find in my Downloads folder. I will then move the results of these files to another directory. I'd like the prompt to loop - allowing me to refine my search terms until I've listed only the files I want.

I've been able to come up with the following. But I've run into the obvious problem of having to copy/paste my `if` statement infinite times potential. Is there a better way to do this? Perhaps put the whole thing in a loop? Here's what I have so far.

```
#!/bin/bash


# This script helps manage files that are found in the Downloads DIRECTORY
# and can relocate them to other directories.


# Set up an if-then statement/loop that allows you to search by extension or
# other wildcard until you find what you're looking for.

echo Searching Downloads directory

read -p 'Search ... [regex]? ' RESPONSE

find Downloads -maxdepth 1 -name "${RESPONSE}"

FOUND=$(find Downloads -maxdepth 1 -name "${RESPONSE}")


# Prompt to move these files



read -p 'Would you like to move these files [y = Yes] ' FILE_MOVE


if [ "$FILE_MOVE" = "y" ]
  then
    read -p 'Which directory? ' DIRECTORY_MOVE
    mv FOUND DIRECTORY_MOVE
  else
    read -p 'Would you like to keep searching [y = Yes] ' KEEP_SEARCHING
fi


if [ "$KEEP_SEARCHING" = "y" ]
  then
    read -p 'Search ... [regex]? ' RESPONSE
    find Downloads -maxdepth 1 -name "${RESPONSE}"
  else
    echo Goodbye!!
fi
```

Comment: Why not use the while loop of bash?

Comment: Again this `find Downloads -maxdepth 1 -name "${RESPONSE}"` will return an result set, so an array will be in order here to store the results! And will this `search string to find in my Downloads folder` search word be for the **foldername** or for a **file** in that folder with such a string?

Comment: I would use an interactive file manager for this kind of task, e.g. `mc` (Midnight Commander). Press `+` to select files based on a shell pattern, or a regex if you uncheck "Using shell patterns". Then press `F6` to move them to the other panel, or any other specified directory. That way you get way more feedback throughout the process, and confirmations if you're about to do something dangerous (such as overwrite an existing file). (Unless, of course, your goal is actually to learn to write shell scripts, rather than move files out of your Downloads folder.)